# Transition Functions for Cartesian Coordinate Systems

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, coordinate-systems

This is my first time using Mathematics SE (I've only used Physics and Astronomy before), so I apologize if this question is awkwardly phrased or incorrectly presented. I welcome any and all edits and suggestions that can make it clearer.

I'm a beginner when it comes to manifolds, and I'm just learning about transition functions. I've been working in Cartesian coordinates, in the Euclidean plane. I have a pair of differentiable functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ on two Cartesian coordinate charts, and I want to find a basic transition function between them. Let's say that $f(x) = 6x^2 + 2$ and $g(x) = 2x^4$. They are defined on separate coordinate charts, which are separated by a translation and a rotation. Is it possible to find a simple transition function between the two charts (possibly independent of the functions)?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  I'm not completely sure what you're asking.  If $f$ and $g$ are functions on a 2-dimensional space, they should have two variables each, i.e. $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. (Unless you're actually working over the complex plane?)  Also, a coordinate chart is a map from a "nice" space, such as Euclidean $n$-space or an open subset of it, to another space.  Do you have two such maps, and they differ by rotating/translating the domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Euclidean plane. Made the edit.

Comment: No need to apologize. But the Euclidean plane is two-dimensional. You cannot take arbitrary products of its elements in any standard way, so $x^2$ and $x^4$ don't make sense if $x$ lies in the Euclidean plane. Perhaps you mean 1-dimensional Euclidean space, i.e. the real line $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think so. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What are the two coordinate charts? Also, what do you mean that the two coordinate charts are separated by a translation and a rotation? Do you just mean that to get from the coordinates on one chart to the other you perform a translation and rotation?

Comment: @JonHerman: Yes to your second and third questions. Really, the charts are coordinate planes.

Comment: In regard's to squirrels comments, your functions $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. A coordinate chart in the Euclidean plane is an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ together with coordinates $x,y$ and a function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f:U\to f(U)$ is an infinitely differentiable isomorphism. So you need your function to be of both $x$ and $y$, otherwise the set $U$ is just a subset or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let me try to explain my question better. In general relativity, there is a transformation matrix $\Lambda^{b}_{a'}$ with which I can transition between coordinates. I want to find out if I can create a similar function even though the coordinates are the same - just in different positions and angles in space.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more precise with your question. Are the entries of the matrix $\Lambda^b_a$ real numbers? Functions of points in space? There may be some issue here with physics language versus mathematical language. For example, suppose you have coordinate charts $\phi: U \to X$ and $\psi: V \to X$ (where $U,V$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$) for the same region in $X$ (i.e. $\phi(U)=\psi(V)$). These maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ are necessarily invertible and the "transition functions" are compositions $\psi^{-1} \circ \phi: U\to V$ and $\phi^{-1} \circ \psi:V \to U$.

Comment: I agree with the language issue. I found this page: http://www.continuummechanics.org/cm/coordxforms.html that I think provides a better idea of what I mean. I was looking for a relationship between the two coordinate planes. However, I think that I can figure my question out using a simple matrix transformation of the basis vectors of the system. Basically, I think the webpage answers my question.